# Passa o mês e o ano quando o usuário clicar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Eu tenho este `input`, que eu gostaria de clicar eu passo o dia, mês e ano que vai aparecer, e não o mês atual, vou precisar fazer uma condição, que já tenho pronta, mas não sei como passar para este `input`

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="paymentDate_i"
       placeholder="{{ 'fields.paymentDate' | translate }}" formControlName="paymentDate"
       name="paymentDate-{{ i }}" (focus)="paymentDate_i.open()" (click)="paymentDate_i.open()"
       required />
```

Eu não quero que a data apareça, eu quero que ao clicar, vim com o mês e ano que eu colocar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o component *mat-datepicker* para obter o resultado desejado.

```
<input matInput  [matDatepicker]="picker">
<mat-datepicker startAt="2018-01-15" #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

Exemplo funcional:
[datepicker](https://stackblitz.com/edit/datepicker-start-at?file=src/app/datepicker-custom-header-example.html)

Comment: Obrigado pela indicação, funcionou certinho.. Obrigado,

Comment: Sim, altere o template para `<mat-datepicker [startAt]="myStartAt"  #picker></mat-datepicker>`. E adicione a variavel no Component `myStartAt = new Date("2018-01-05")`